# iterating through a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have around around 20000 text files, numbered 1.txt,2.txt and so on..

Now, i am creating a dictionary d containing the filepaths to the files 5.txt,10.txt,15.txt and so on..

```
d[value]=filepath

ex:
d[5]=d:/articles/5.txt
d[45]=d:/articles/45.txt
```

and i have a text file "temp.txt" with a list of 500 words

```
vs
mln
money
```

and so on..

now for each text file in dictionary "d", i need to record the frequency of occurrence of all the words in the list.

So,I create a nested dictionary of the form d2[word][file]=count(is it the right approach?)

```
where, d2[vs][5]=number of times "vs" occurs in 5.txt
```

In short, for every file, i iterate through the list of words and count its occurrences.

how do i create d2?

my bad code is:

```
import collections, sys, os, re

sys.stdout=open('3.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob

folderpath='d:/individual-articles'
folderpaths='d:/individual-articles/'
counter=Counter()
filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))

# returns the next word in the file
def words_generator(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

d= collections.defaultdict(list)

#to print the filenames:(creation of d)

with open('topics.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        value=(line.split('~')[0])
        if int(value)%5==0:
            file=folderpaths+value+'.txt'
            d[value].append(file)

d2= collections.defaultdict(list)

for file in filepaths:
    f = open(file,"r")
    words = words_generator(f)
    for word in words:
        if  file in d[file]:
            d2[word][file]+= 1              
#i have no idea how to go further, beyond this point.
```

Plz help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import os
from collections import Counter,defaultdict
d2 = defaultdict(dict)
word_list = ['vs', 'mln', 'money']
for fil in d.values():
    with open(fil[0]) as f:
       path, name = os.path.split(fil[0])
       words_c = Counter([word for line in f for word in line.split()])
       for word in word_list:
           d2[word][name] = words_c[word]
```

Now access d2 as:

```
d2['vs']['5.txt']
```

Comment: @Elazar yes, that should also work fine. I tried to stick to OP's requirement : `d2[word][file]`

Comment: I posted this version too. Hope you don't mind your answer being copied :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i get an error! Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: invalid file: ['d:/individual-articles/13400.txt']

Comment: `d` contains lists or simple strings?

Comment: strings, which are file paths

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary should it be lists?

Comment: @PokerFace if `d` contains only strings then it should work fine, `d` is a dict right?

Comment: @PokerFace please post some sample data then, I am not sure what is wrong here. :/

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: when i print "d":defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'15145': ['d:/individual-articles/15145.txt'], '1465': ['d:/individual-articles/1465.txt'], '7635': ['d:/individual-articles/7635.txt']...i get this..

Comment: i guess there is some kind of error in d..could u suggest an alternative to d,i.e; instead of a dictionary, could i store it in a list?

Comment: @PokerFace I was correct, `d` contains lists not strings. I've updated my code.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: wat if i do this?i get an output..but is it correct?with open('3.txt', 'r') as fi:
    list2= [line.strip() for line in fi]


with open('temp.txt', 'r') as fi:
    list= [line.strip() for line in fi]



d2 =defaultdict(dict)
for fil in list2:
    with open(fil) as f:
       path, name = os.path.split(fil)
       words_c = Counter([word for line in f for word in line.split()])
       for word in list:
           d2[word][name] = words_c[word]

Comment: here '3.txt' contains the list of files,which was initially stored in the dictionary "d" and "temp.txt" contains the list of words...so i am totally eliminating the use of d..is it correct?As, i create two lists..

Comment: @PokerFace It should work fine. Store the words from `temp.txt` in the `word_list` and then simply loop over the filenames fetched from `3.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can swap the dictionaries, you can have @Ashwini Chaudhary's answer somewhat simplified (though maybe a little less efficient):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

with open('temp.txt') as f:
    word_list = set(f.read.split())

d2 = defaultdict(Counter)
for n in range(number_of_files):
    with open('{}.txt'.format(n)) as f:
        d2[fil] = Counter([word for word in f.read().split() if word in word_list])
```